# Revoke [plotly] tag synonym [r-plotly]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-removal-request

Recently the [r-plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-plotly) tag referring to the [R library plotly](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R) became a synonym for the [plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plotly) tag referring to the [JS library plotly](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/).

I think this should be undone, as it makes filtering the questions more difficult.

The usage guidance for [plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plotly) suggests:

> Plotly.js is an open source, high-level, declarative charting library,
> built on top of d3.js and stack.gl. It ships with over 40 chart types,
> including 3D charts, statistical graphs, and SVG maps. Use [r-plotly]
> for the R package and [plotly-python] for the Python package.

which for me worked fine in the past years.

Comment: Might also want to rename [plotly] to [plotly.js] to disambiguate, but possibly need to clean up first...

Comment: Note that, although there is a synonym mapping in place, the tags have not been *merged*, so there are 1241 questions tagged [r-plotly], you just can't see that in the user interface, because those are getting remapped to [plotly] (of which there are 12235 questions with that tag).

Comment: Are they not all the same family of libraries? https://plotly.com/graphing-libraries/

Comment: If we're going to separate them out, it seems like we should at least rename the "base" [plotly] tag to [plotly-js], and then have [plotly-r], [plotly-python], etc.  But also I'm not sure that's better than [plotly] [javascript], [plotly] [r], etc.

Comment: @RyanM yes, the R and python libraries are wrappers for the JS library. Nevertheless, different languages are used on the top-level to generate the charts.

Comment: So why not just use [plotly] and a language tag, then?

Comment: As stated above I'd argue that it is more convenient to have a unique tag for each library for filtering or watching the tag (btw. the pyhon and R libraries differ regarding their scope of functions although having the same JS base). In the end of course, the same can be achived by a combination of [r] and [plotly] and custom filters but those are extra steps to take. However, the current situation is inconsistent (R tag being a synonym, python tag remaining separate) and should be amended independent of my personal preference.